# MSBuild.Community.Tasks Unzip task makes console output bloat

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I use the following code to unzip archive with MSBuild Community Task `Unzip`:

```
<Target Name="Sandbox">
    <Unzip 
        ZipFileName="text.zip" 
        TargetDirectory="Unzip" />
</Target>
```

`text.zip` contains one file text.txt, its size is 716 bytes.

And I obtain several line on console during file extraction:

```
...
extracted "text.txt"
extracted "text.txt"
extracted "text.txt"
...
```

3 times for tiny 716 bytes file!

And for large files `Unzip` task fills console with much more lines: larger file - more lines.

I had 1 line per file in MSBuild Community Tasks 1.2.0.306, but versions 1.3.0.493 and 1.4.0.42 outputs much more lines for single file.

Is it possible to obtain one line per file in new releases of MSBuild community tasks?

I don't know if such behavior is by new design or a bug.

Comment: Might be a VS artefact. I have seen similar duplicated output from running post build events in the Output Window.

Comment: I run via command line "msbuild sandbox.proj"

Comment: I would contact the authors of the project then and report a the issue. Is there no way you can turn the output off? It seems silly to show.

Comment: I have not found how to disable output at all. I investigated dll with Unzip task with ILSpy - nothing concerning this

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug. I reported it to upstream (https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/pull/26) fixed it and it got merged 9 days ago. Should be corrected in the next release.